# hadoop 2.6 cluster cannot be initialized. Successfully run with local jars, but not maven dependency

Tags: eclipse, maven, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I'm trying to debug wordcount sample using apache hadoop 2.6.0.I create the project in eclipse. My first try was configure the build path and include all the hadoop jar files (extracted from hadoop folder) in the buildpath. I can successfully run the word count and get the result. Then my second try is to make this project a 'maven' project and using pom.xml to specify needed hadoop jars (and remove local jars in buildpath). Here comes the problem. This time exception throws as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1262)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:59)
```

My wordcount code is pretty simple and classic wordcount.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
              ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
          sum += val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Configuration conf = new Configuration();
      Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
      job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
      job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
      job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
      job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
      job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/home/jsun/share/wc/input"));              
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/home/jsun/share/wc/output"));
      System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
  }
```

And the pom.xml for maven:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>wordcount2</groupId>
  <artifactId>wordcount2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <repositories>                                                                                     
    <repository>
      <id>apache</id>
      <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

What is the difference using local hadoop jars and using maven dependencies?
Is that a problem of cluster or the wordcount or using maven?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

please check this [Link](http://www.eclpeople.com/how-to-run-a-map-reduce-job-using-java-jar-command-qq-AUvBU3U3ivICeoL1jOmL.php) 
 i had the same issue and i don't have hadoop installed on my machine. you can't run the program without installation. i think it looks for some environment variables to run hadoop commands.

Hope this helps